# Is "org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:exec" supposed to fail to execute the goal when there are failed tests in JUnit?

Tags: maven, cucumber, bdd

When one of the tests fail in my maven project I get the following error:
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:exec (default) on project java: Command execution failed.: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]

I'm trying to automate my tests using Hiptest and TravisCI. I forked the hps-cucumber-java project from Hiptest and followed the guide. When all the tests pass, it works as expected. But when one of them fail (Using assertTrue(false)) it gives me the following error:

```
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:exec (default) on project java: Command execution failed.: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
```

Is this somehow supposed to happen when tests fail? The cuke-results.json file is generated with no problems but that error messes up TravisCI and prevents the results from being uploaded to Hiptest.

This is my pom file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.coffeemachine</groupId>
  <artifactId>java</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>java</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
 <build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.1</version>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.16</version>
        <configuration>
            <skipTests>true</skipTests>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>test</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>exec</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <classpathScope>test</classpathScope>
                    <executable>java</executable>
                    <arguments>
                        <argument>-classpath</argument>
                        <classpath />
                        <argument>cucumber.api.cli.Main</argument>
                        <argument>--plugin</argument>
                        <argument>json:${project.build.directory}/cuke-results.json</argument>
                        <argument>--glue</argument>
                        <argument>com.coffeemachine</argument>
                        <argument>--strict</argument>
                        <argument>${basedir}/src/test/java/com/coffeemachine</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
      <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.3</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
      <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.3</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm Houda from HipTest team!

I suppose that there is a wrong implementation in your Actionwords.java file or rather in one of your files on which your tests are based.

Here is an example that could help you, you will find [here](https://github.com/hiptest/hps-cucumber-java/) a GitHub repository based on Cucumber-Java and our sample project "Coffee Machine".

In [this main file](https://github.com/hiptest/hps-cucumber-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/coffeemachine/CoffeeMachine.java) on which the tests are based, you have a "coffeeServed" variable declared to false in the "CoffeeMachine" class.

At the same time, the "CoffeeMachine" class is declared as a new object in this [Actionwords.java](https://github.com/hiptest/hps-cucumber-java/blob/master/src/test/java/com/coffeemachine/Actionwords.java) file, and the "coffeeServed" variable is integreted into the "assertTrue()" method as a value.

Can you try to modify the structure of your tests in order to obtain a similar implementation and try to run your tests again? Do you have the same error in the output?

Comment: Still didn't work out after I did all you said. But I set up a new project using Cucumber tutorial here: https://cucumber.io/docs/guides/10-minute-tutorial/

I configured it using hiptest-publisher.conf file that was created by Hiptest>Project>Automation>Download Code section. And I copied and modified .travis.yml file from the hps-cucumber-java project. It works now but when I publish using cmd there is an import as "cucumber.api.DataTable" and it gives an error. How can I configure my hiptest-publisher.conf file to not import that or import it as "io.cucumber.datatable.*"?

Comment: Do you have a datatable in one or more in your scenarios? May you send me the returned error?